# Google Script update button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you please help me why its not working everytime i click on button. I want to get the old value of column J and column K and set it to column L and M. Please help me TIA.

```
    function         submitValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  // Get the value from C11 on Sheet1
  var cellC11 = sheet1.getRange("C11").getValue();

  // Get the current date and time
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Set the value of C11 from Sheet1 to Sheet2 in column J and set a new date in column K
  sheet2.getRange("J1").setValue(cellC11);
  sheet2.getRange("K1").setValue(currentDate);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var range = e.range;

  if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet2") {
    if (range.getColumn() === 10) { // Column J is column 10
      var oldValue = e.oldValue;
      var newValue = e.value;

      if (oldValue !== newValue) {
        // Set the previous value in column L
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 12).setValue(oldValue);
      }
    } else if (range.getColumn() === 11) { // Column K is column 11
      var oldDate = e.oldValue;
      var newDate = e.value;

      if (oldDate !== newDate) {
        // Set the previous date in column M
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 13).setValue(oldDate);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to get the previous value of column J and Column K and set value to Column L and M. it only works when i manually type the value on the column

Comment: The `onEdit(e)` event trigger knows what the old value was before you changed it, so you can get `e.oldValue`.  With your submit button there is no `oldValue` only the value in the cell at the time you click the button.

Comment: Why is it like that? If i change the value of C11 automatically change the value of column J and K and it works if manually input on column J. But when i used the button its not working can you please help me modify my code? Thanks

Comment: As I said `onEdit(e)` is an event trigger.  When you type something in the cell and press enter, the `onEdit` event stores the old value and puts the new value in the cell.  But once the event is over the old value is lost.  When you click a button it executes a function but that function doesn't know any old value only the latest value in the cell.  There is no simple work around that I know of.

Comment: If there anything i can do to achieved my desire results?

Comment: `I want to get the old value of column J and column K and set it to column L and M.` Have you tried capturing those values, updating the cells in Column L&M and THEN set the values in Columns J&K.